# Unable to load Llama 2 (7b) model in Docker container

Tags: docker, flask, llama, ctransformers

I am trying to containerize simple Flask application which performs inference on `llama-2-7b.Q5_K_M.gguf` model. Flask application is running fine it loads the model successfully but when I am trying run the Flask application with Docker container, it is throwing below error.

```
  File "/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    llm_llama2_7b = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/hub.py", line 175, in from_pretrained
    llm = LLM(
          ^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/llm.py", line 246, in __init__
    self._lib = load_library(lib, gpu=config.gpu_layers > 0)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/llm.py", line 126, in load_library
    lib = CDLL(path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/lib/basic/libctransformers.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Code Directory**

[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.11.6-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

app = Flask(__name__)

llm_llama2_7b = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("models/llama-2-7b.Q5_K_M.gguf", model_type="llama")
print("Model loaded")

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
ctransformers
```

Comment: Error messages should be _text_, not screenshots of text; see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Getting to the core of the question, though -- the error message means exactly what it says: the dependencies of your module need to be available in the container. You can use `ldd` to list those dependencies -- but generally, you can avoid this class of problem if the ctransformers module is compiled against the same environment (distro version, installed libraries, etc) that you're using it in.

Comment: (specifically, run `ldd /usr/local/lib/.../libctransformers.so` and see what it says is missing -- I'd have a full, runnable command in this comment, but _you didn't give us text we can copy-and-paste from_)

Comment: ...personally, btw, I avoid this class of problem by using [Nix](https://nixos.org/) for package management. It _mostly_ makes Docker unnecessary altogether, but if one _does_ have a reason to use both Nix and Docker together, [dockerTools](https://ryantm.github.io/nixpkgs/builders/images/dockertools/) can assemble a container with a full dependency set of any software you have a Nix description of how to build. (CUDA can make things a little hairy, but it's doable -- see the flake.nix for LMQL for an example of building llama-cpp-python, which is pretty similar dependency-set-wise).

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy I have updated the error message as text

Comment: Thank you. Could you also give us the output from running `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/lib/basic/libctransformers.so` in your container? (I'm assuming the file itself exists but one of its dependencies does not; if the file itself doesn't exist, that's a different isuse).

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy sorry for the late reply, actually container is getting crashed hence I cannot execute the command you mentioned.

Comment: Run the container with an interactive shell as the parent process, don't use the default command. (That is to say: Use something like `docker run -it YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME bash` to force `bash` to override the default of invoking `flask run`).

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy after going inside container using bash I ran the command you mentioned it throws following message. 

`/app# ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/lib/basic/libctransformers.so
 not a dynamic executable`

Comment: Okay, so we know it's not a shared object for the right platform; does `file /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ctransformers/lib/basic/libctransformers.so` tell you something about what it is instead?